# How to reduce expressions with complex coefficients in the form of a+0.*I

Tags: complex, simplifying-expressions

I'm trying to get an eigenvalue equation in Mathematica, and the result is an expression with coefficients of the form `a + 0. I`. For example,

[image: Mathematica output]

Is there any clever way to simplify it? I mean the method in which I can take away the `0.*I` in the expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `Chop[]` works nicely here.

```
Chop[1 + 0. I]
1.
```

Comment: @yulinlinyu: However note that `Chop` changes every approximate value near zero to zero. Usually it is what you want, but you should be aware of it for the cases when you *don't* want to replace a numerical value of order $10^{-11}$ or below with zero (sometimes that's just the order of magnitude your numbers are expected to be in). In such cases, the optional second argument of `Chop` comes in handy.

Comment: @celt: good note. At least in OP's case, this isn't a worry, but still good to be wary when your expression has a mix of genuinely tiny constants and stuff that really ought to be zero.