# How to make the imaginary part of a +0. I zero globally?

Tags: complex

Values like a +0. I are really annoying. Answers from

[How to reduce expressions with complex coefficients in the form of a+0.*I？](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6884/how-to-reduce-expressions-with-complex-coefficients-in-the-form-of-a0-i)
 [Is there a way to globally set when to treat a very small number as zero?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14526/is-there-a-way-to-globally-set-when-to-treat-a-very-small-number-as-zero)

give me some clue, but I find `$Post = Chop[#, 10^-16] &;`  doesn't work, for example :

```
Print[MatrixForm[FourierDCT[FourierDCT[{0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 2], 3]]]
```

gives (0.  -5.55112*10^-17  1.  1.38778*10^-17  1.38778*10^-17 ), which means the small digits still exist.

Comment: What's wrong with `Print[MatrixForm[FourierDCT[FourierDCT[{0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 2], 3] // Chop]]`? You can't use `Chop` outside the MatrixForm if that's the problem you've been having.

Comment: But you know, it's probably a mistake to try to *always* hide small numbers --- someday you may need to know that they are not really zero. Just choose `Chop` whenever you want to display things.

Comment: Jonathan Shock: I don't know Chop fails outside the MatrixForm. But doesn't $Post = Chop[#, 10^-16] &; tells Mathematica to neglect digits smaller than 10^-16 automatically？

Comment: @bills But isn't `$Post` (or `$PrePrint`) just the right thing to use whenever one wants to display things? The problem here is that it won't apply to `Print`ed output (try it without the `Print` statement).

Comment: @bills, what if I need to compare a to an integer like If[a>3,..,..], whereas a is actually a + 0.I? Then error occurs.

Comment: @novice, the `$Post` command will apply this to the output expression but given that the expression itself is generated using `MatrixForm` I don't expect it to work on the numbers inside it. Try applying `Chop` to your `MatrixForm` expression and see what it does.

Comment: @Jonathan Shock Is there a way to confine all the numbers to real numbers in a program? Because I don't need imaginary number.

Comment: The default for all numbers is Complex. But if you use only rationals (and don't do stuff like `Sqrt[-rational]` then everything will remain rational. But if you do operations that generate complex numbers (like `Sqrt` or roots of polynmials, there are lots!) then you need to deal with it explicitly. You can always apply `Re` to take only the real part or `Chop` to remove small imaginary values.

Comment: Keep in mind that an array that contains both pure reals and complexes can't be packed, so it'll take more memory and calculations will be slower.  An array with all complexes (some of which have imaginary part 0.) can be packed without problems.

Comment: Related: [(3736)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3736/121), [(24785)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24785/121)

Answer (score 5):

```
$PrePrint = Chop
```

will work fine for suppressing small approximate numbers in the display of your results. However, it won't have an effect on the the output generated by `Print`:

```
expr = FourierDCT[FourierDCT[{0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 2], 3]
```

> `{0, 0, 1., 0, 0}`

```
Print[expr]
```

> `{0., 0., 1., 2.64289*10^-17, 1.54951*10^-18}`

That's because `$PrePrint` (and also `$Post`) are applied after the expression has evaluated, which means (counter-intuitively) that `Print` has already printed by the time that `$PrePrint` does anything. (`MatrixForm` has nothing to do with the problem.)

To get `Print` to go along with the program, you could inject a `Chop` into it using the  [Villegas-Gayley hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149656/1381569):

```
Unprotect[Print]; 
Module[{inside}, 
  Print[expr__] /; ! TrueQ[inside] := 
    Block[{inside = True}, Print @@ Chop@{expr}]
]
Protect[Print];
```

Now we have

```
Print[expr]
```

> `{0, 0, 1., 0, 0}`

Note that this kind of thing may lead you into trouble, since the display of `expr` now doesn't match its internal representation. For example, if you want to find the positions of the zero elements, by looking at the displayed form, you might think that `Position[expr, 0]` would do the trick. But really you would need `Position[expr, _?(Chop[#] == 0 &)]` (or `Position[Chop@expr, 0]`).