# Length of a graph of a function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The question is as follows:

Calculate the length of the graph of the function $f(x)=e^x$ between $x=0$ and $x=1$.

Use this: $\alpha =\int_a^b \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}\right)^2+1} \, dx$

I made a graph to view:

```
f[x_] := E^x
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
α = Integrate[Sqrt[D[f[x], {x}]^2 + 1], {x, 0, 1}]
```

> $-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{1+e^2}+\tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)-\tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1+e^2}\right)$

```
N[α]
```

> $2.0035\, +0. i$

But this result I did not understand. Was it not supposed to return a real value?

Comment: Mathematica automatically works with complex numbers, use Chop. [6884](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6884/5478)

Comment: If you're not interested in the closed form, just use `NIntegrate[]` directly. `Integrate[Sqrt[Exp[2 x] + 1], {x, 0, 1}] // TrigToExp // FullSimplify` yields a result that does not give a spurious imaginary part after being treated with `N[]`.

Comment: If you want the most direct WL approach, you could use: `ArcLength[Exp[x], {x, 0, 1}]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
f[x_] := E^x
a = Integrate[Sqrt[D[f[x], {x}]^2 + 1], {x, 0, 1}]
```

> $-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{1+e^2}+\tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)-\tanh
>    ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1+e^2}\right)$

The same is obtained with `ArcLength[Exp[x], {x, 0, 1}]`.

```
N @ a
```

> 2.0035 + 0. I

The imaginary part is a numerical artifact; check, e.g.

```
N[a, 30]
```

> 2.00349711162735247856990275242 + 0.*10^-30 I

and

```
N[a, 50]
```

> 2.0034971116273524785699027524202391308211427952321 + 0.*10^-50 I

In fact, `N[a, p]` gives a result in the form `real part + 0.*10^-p I` for every `p` $-$ the imaginary part is a numerical zero due to working with inexact numbers.

The simplest thing to do is

```
N[a] // Chop
```

> 2.0035

or slightly more elaborate

```
TrigToExp[a] // N
```

> 2.0035

Comment: ComplexExpand often helps with spurious real/imaginary parts. In this case, N@ComplexExpand@a also produces the real answer.

Comment: @CarlWoll `ComplexExpand@a` in this case gives the same as `TrigToExp@a`.